# How to train Sentence Recognizer in Spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to detect and extract sentences from legal cases. Each paragraph in these cases starts with a number:

> 23 The main issue for determination therefore....

> 7 The Appellant’s factual witness...

Right now, Spacy's Sentence Recognizer extracts the above as sentences. I would like to train it such that it 'ignores' the leading digits and detects the sentences as starting after the digits.

The code I have thus far is:

```
import spacy
from spacy.training import Example

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
senter = nlp.add_pipe("senter", name="my_senter")

doc = nlp("32 It should be noted that each step")
tokens_ref = ["32", "It", "should", "be", "noted", "that", "each", "step"]
sents_ref = [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]
examples = Example.from_dict(doc, {"words": tokens_ref, "sent_starts": sents_ref})
split_examples = examples.split_sents()
senter.initialize(lambda: split_examples, nlp=nlp)
```

I am not sure whether the above code is accurate and works. I'm also unsure how I can:

1. Pass multiple training examples at one go
2. Save the trained sentence recognizer and use it again

I would appreciate any help in this regard. I'm fairly new to using Spacy and could not find much resources on training the Sentence Recognizer.

I am aware that I can use other methods to remove the leading digits in each line. Nonetheless, I would still like to know how to train Spacy to try and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should create data in spacy format. For example:

```
data_train = [("32 It should be noted that each step", {'sent_starts': [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]})]
```

Next step:

```
nlp = spacy.blank('xx')
nlp.add_pipe('senter')

print(f'Pipline: {nlp.pipe_names}')
print(nlp.analyze_pipes(pretty=True))

optimizer = nlp.begin_training()  

other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'senter']
with nlp.disable_pipes([]): #*other_pipes
    for epoch in tqdm(range(1, 20+1)):
        random.shuffle(data_train)
        losses = {}
        for batch in spacy.util.minibatch(data_train, size=4):
            example = None
            for text, annotations in batch:
                doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
                example = Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
                nlp.update([example], sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
            print('Losses', losses)
```